# Solr Cloud: How to disable document (pdf, office) metadata as fields

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud, solr-schema

I am new to Solr and using Solr 7.3.1 in solr cloud mode
and trying to index pdf, office documents in solr, using contentextraction in solr.

I created a collection with
`bin\solr create -c tsindex -s 2 -rf 2`

in SolrJ my code looks like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Solr Indexer");
    final String solrUrl = "http://localhost:8983/solr/tsindex/";
    HttpSolrClient solr = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(solrUrl).build();
    String filename="C:\\iSampleDocs\\doc-file.doc";    
    ContentStreamUpdateRequest solrRequest = new ContentStreamUpdateRequest("/update/extract");
    try {
        solrRequest.addFile(new File(filename), "application/msword");
        solrRequest.setParam("litral.ts_ref", "ts-456123");
        //solrRequest.setParam("defaultField", "text");

        solrRequest.setAction(AbstractUpdateRequest.ACTION.COMMIT, true, true);
        NamedList<Object> result= solr.request(solrRequest);
        System.out.println(result);

    } catch (IOException  e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch ( SolrServerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am getting multiple issues

1. Although I have created field `ts_ref` as `text_general` in Solr Admin UI, this field does not get set at all.
2. My goal is to index the complete document including its metadata in one field and then set couple of more fileds refrencing document in another system like e.g. ts_ref field. But what actually happens is the solr extracts the metadata of files and create seperate fileds for each metadata value.

I have tried disabling  `data driven schema functionality` by `bin\solr config -c tsindex -zkHost localhost:9983 -property update.autoCreateFields -value false`

When I uncomment line `solrRequest.setParam("defaultField", "text");` from beginning, there is not separate fields for all metadata extracted, but as soon as I comment this line and upload the files, the meta data are again in separate fields afterwards (even if I uncomment its again).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. "litral.ts_ref" there is a typo here, missing an e
2. you can achieve ignoring all metadata fields by using uprefix field, and a dynamic field that goes with it. See the [doc](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/uploading-data-with-solr-cell-using-apache-tika.html) that shows exactly that case.